# Unity5 mixing animations with different properties

Tags: unity, animation

Maybe there are tons of questions about this but i dont know what to look for. I have 2 animations, one is aiming a weapon and the other one is shooting.

When i aim the weapon i animate only its position upward and a little bit to the left so its in front of the camera.

When i shoot, i just rotate it a bit on the x-axis.

My problem is, when i shoot while the weapon is aimed (animated upwards and left) the whole Weaponholder get back to its initial (not aimed) position.

I thought when i just animate the position in one clip and only rotation in another i can mix them together. Am i on the wrong way or just did something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us how you're currently layering/blending these animations in your controller graph?

Comment: I dont, currently i split it into 2 animations, one from idle to shoot and one from aimed to shoot. Do you try to say layering/blending is the way to go for me?

Comment: It's worth [reviewing the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html) at least, to see if you can find a solution there.

Comment: Ii dont talk about animating parts of an object consisting of multiple entities. I talk about a simple primitive Cube for e.g - no upper/lower body mixing. Its like mixing upper/upper body in 2 ways. For example a hand. i want to turn it up - but sometimes while the hand is up it shoult also rotate. PS: i reviewed the "documentation" (how they call it) but its totally outdated/not actual in any ways. Your link leads me to a 503 error anyways..

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what additive layering can accomplish.

Comment: Thank you. But the 5th sentence tell me to specify which mask to use for my parts. Which parts does a cube have to separate?

Comment: No answer is also an answer

Comment: No, the fifth sentence says you *can* use a mask. Nowhere does it say that you *must*. Since a mask is not applicable to your case, you don't use a mask.